# how to delete all the contents of a disk via plsql

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a folder in the server

/home/test/pictures

There are multiple .jpg files inside this pictures folder.

I want to delete these files from this pictures using plsql.

Is there a utility for this ?

Comment: This is a very strange use for a querying / data-retrieval language.

Comment: Hi Radu. I need to do this because i am creating new jpg files in each run. so i want to delete the existing contents before new creation

Answer (score 2):

you can use UTL_FILE.FREMOVE function this function will remove files from a directory, here is the parameters for the function UTL_FILE.FREMOVE (location IN VARCHAR2,filename IN VARCHAR2)

location should be in  ALL_DIRECTORIES view

so calling a function would be like this:

```
begin
  UTL_FILE.FREMOVE('C:\','TEXT.TXT');--this will remove text.txt from C drive
end;
```

you can read this article https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_file.htm#BABEGHIG

Comment: I want to delete all the contents of this drive and not hard code it like 'TEXT.TXT'

Comment: Google "read contents of directory pl/sql" - there are lots of links with different approaches to consider.